# How to Print Alphabet sequentially in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array variable `$arr = array('A','B','C','D');`

```
$number = 5; (This is dynamic)
```

My new array value should be

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I');
```

If

```
$number = 3;
```

Output should be:

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G');
```

If `$number` variable will come more than `22` then print array from `A` to `Z` and with `AA, AB, AC..` etc.

How to do that in PHP code?

Comment: Please rephrase your question and why 22? there are a total of 26 alphabets.

Comment: @Mark already there have `4` array values exist. so I have given `22` You can put any number instead of 22

Comment: Using a for loop and convert the iterating variable info à ASCII character (if I remember add 0x41 to the variable value)

Comment: @Mark  I have edited my question. Could you please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one: https://3v4l.org/IGhoL

```
<?php

/**
 * Increments letter
 * @param int   $number
 * @param array &$arr
 */
function increment($number, &$arr) {
    $char = end($arr);
    $char++;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++, $char++) {
        $arr[] = $char;
    }
}

$arr = range('A', 'D');
$number = 30;

increment($number, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increment letters by incrementing it, then store it that array itself. This will print two letter sequence also ie., AA, AB ...

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D'); 
$item = end($arr) ;
$i = 0 ;
while( $i++ < $number ) {
    $arr[] = ++$item  ;
}
print_r($arr) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example to add chars from alphabet to array with offset. This works for one char. If you wish to work for more chars use loop in loop.

```
for ($c = ord('A') + $offset ;$c <= ord('Z');$c++) {
  Array[] += chr($c);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
$arr = array(A,B,C,D,E);
$data = range('F','Z');
$num = 4;

if($num < 22){
    $output = array_merge($arr,array_slice($data, 0, $num));    
}else{
     // Write ur format here..
    // $output = array('AA','AB',......,'AZ');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```